# Spring cloud stream : Attempted to pause a component that does not support Pausable bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

I'm new to spring cloud stream. I am using a binder written by one of our team members.
I use the */bindings* endpoint of actuator to pause/resume a consumer in my application. But I'm getting an error

```
o.s.c.s.b.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$2 : Attempted to pause a component that does not support Pausable bean 'XXX'
```

Qn 1.  I'm guessing it's because the binder that I'm using is not supporting the pause/resume operations. Can anybody point me to some examples, where I can find how to add this feature to the binder ?

Qn 2. I tried start/stop also using the actuator endpoint. Stop is working fine but, while doing start, I'm getting the below error

```
o.s.c.s.b.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$2 : Can not re-bind an anonymous binding
```

Can someone give some inputs regarding this error too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is anonymous since `group` name is generated based on the function name. And that is what the error message is telling you. You have to explicitly declare a group name.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.destination=myDestination
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.group=myGroup
```

You can get more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names)

Comment: Thanks Oleg.. That worked for me. To solve that issue.

Comment: But for some reason while starting the consumers again the threadpoolexecutor is rejecting the execution.

it says 'Task xxx rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@79b77df2[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]'

Comment: You posted a fragment of something that provides no relevant information, so nothing to answer here

Answer (score 0):

It's not the binder, rather the underlying functionality of the actual broker. Only Kafka supports pausing which has a special meaning within Kafka; where *pausing* the consumer will NOT cause consumer rebalancing while *stopping* consumer will.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the answer..
What about the error I'm getting while I stop the consumer. 'Can not re-bind an anonymous binding'.. I'm able to stop it, but afterwards not able to start.

Comment: Instead of actuator endpoints, I tried to use the BindingsLifecycleController bean to change the states, but causes the same issues, as mentioned in the question..